# iPhone OS/SDK Programming Info

Tags: iphone

I'm considering developing for the iPhone and i wanted to know; what codebase does the SDK and any frameworks offer? how easy is it to make a touch enabled application? is there an easy way to tell if, say, someone is attempting to use a zoom out gesture or am i supposed to interpret that myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone SDK is mature. It has a wonderful set of easy to use UI classes and a lot of helpful frameworks for all kinds of purposes. It is fun to write beautiful user interfaces for the iPhone.

Where the SDK lacks support, there's usually an open source alternative, for example regex support.

For your example: UIScrollView is a class that takes care of gestures for zooming, among others.